# Glassfish or JBoss server needs JDK or is it enoug with JRE

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish

I want to Install a Glassfish or JBoss server in a computer wuthout GUI. I would like to know if I must install JDK or if it is enough with JRE to run my JavaEE applications?

Comment: If you just need to run the server, then JRE is enough.

Comment: So if I just want to run an EAR file that I can copy it from another computer where I developed the code an compiled it to my server is enough with JRE?

Comment: I would like to know if I want to develop java web apps do I need to install IcedTea plugin or is it enough with OpenJDK?